# Problems with functions in classes C++ (LNK2019 & LNK1120 errors)

Tags: c++, class, linker-errors, member-functions

I've been working on a project for my college class that uses classes in c++, unfortunately anytime I try to call on a function that is passed parameters within my class the program fails to compile with the two following errors:

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl binsearch(class Course * * const,int,char * const)" (?binsearch@@YAHQAPAVCourse@@HQAD@Z) referenced in function _main   Project1    C:\Users\cvos\source\repos\Project1\Project1\courses_main.obj   1

and

> Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Project1    C:\Users\cvos\source\repos\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe  1

I've looked up the LNK problems, and most results suggest it's something related to symbols in c++ vs c (That fix doesn't work) or that there is a problem with linking the files within visual studio (That fix also didn't work), and finally that it was something to do with it needing to be on the console subsystem (Which it already was).

The strange thing is, if I comment out my calls to all of the functions I've made in the "Course" class that are passed parameters, the program runs fine. It's only when I am trying to use the functions created in the "Course" class that the program fails to run, leading me to suspect strongly I'm doing something wrong with how I'm passing variables to my member functions.

I'll post the relevant parts of my code:

Within my header file "courses.h" I declare my function:

```
int binsearch(Course* co_ptr[], int size, char search[]);
```

Within my 2nd source file "courses_functions.cpp" I define the function:

```
int Course::binsearch(Course* co_ptr[], int size, char search[])
{
    int low = 0, high = size - 1, first_index = -1, last_index = -1, num_of_entries = 0;

    while (low <= high)
    {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (co_ptr[mid]->name == search)
        {
            bool found = false;
            int i = mid;

            while (!found) //Check values below mid
            {
                if (co_ptr[i]->name == search)
                {
                    first_index = i; //first_index now holds a potential first occurence of our name
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                }

                i--; //decrement i and check again.
            }

            i = mid; //Reset i
            found = false; //Reset found

            while (!found) //Check values above mid
            {
                if (co_ptr[i]->name == search)
                {
                    last_index = i; //last_index now holds a potential last occurence of our name
                    if (i == size - 1)
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                }

                i++; //increment i and check again.
            }
            break; //Breaks us out of the main while loop
        }
        else if (co_ptr[mid]->name < search)
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    if ((first_index != -1) && (last_index != -1))
    {
        for (int i = first_index; i <= last_index; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "\nEntry found: "
                << std::endl << co_ptr[i]->name << ' ' << co_ptr[i]->units << " units, grade:" << co_ptr[i]->grade;
            num_of_entries++;
        }
        return num_of_entries;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nEntry not found.";
        return num_of_entries;
    }
}
```

Lastly in my main source file "courses_main.cpp" I call the function:

```
else if (selection == 3) //Display a course
        {
            char title[50] = "";
            int results = 0;

            std::cout << "\nEnter a class to search for: ";
            std::cin.getline(title, 50, '\n');
            std::cin.ignore();
            results = binsearch(courses, size, title);
        }
```

As this is for a college class, I'm not looking to use any alternative methods, I'm mainly trying to figure out why the method I'm using would return the errors I shared above, but I will gladly post more snippets of my code if it is necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to check if there is a function that you declared but not implemented.

Comment: `binsearch` is not a free function, it is a class method, so you either need to declare it `static`, move it outside of your `Course` class, or call it from an instance like `course.binsearch(courses, size, title);`

Comment: @CoryKramer When I move it outside of my Course class it works (I ported it previously from a different program I'd made prior to this university class). 

Adding static results in the same issue as previously (LNK2019 and LNK1120 errors), the last suggestion you made I get these errors:

Error (active) E0254 type name is not allowed Project1

and

Error C2275 'Course': illegal use of this type as an expression Project1

Though I'm completely unfamiliar with what your last suggestion is

Comment: @0xBlackMirror There aren't any functions that are declared but have no definition unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The cause is almost certainly one of the following:

1. You're not compiling the implementation file (just using the header elsewhere).
2. You're compiling the implementation, but not using the compiled object in the linking of objects into the executable.
3. You have some minor mismatch in naming, e.g. using `binsearch()` not in a class context, or using a slightly different signature somehow (not likely giving what you've told us).

Comment: How would I go about fixing case 2? I ask because other functions inside of the class work so long as I am not passing parameters to them. 

An example of this is my void read() function which I use to collect input from the user, it works just fine and is declared and defined in the same spots as my binsearch function is.

Comment: That would require knowledge of MS Visual Studio which I don't have, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see a declaration of your "courses.h" file. You may have declared binsearch outside of your `Course` class declaration. In which case you will get a linker error as mentioned.
Based on your usage in main.. your implementation of this function need not be in `Course` class, it can be a standalone function outside of Course class. once you move your function definition outside of `Course` class, your linker should go away, provided you have courses_functions.cpp and courses_main.cpp files in same project in your MSVC IDE.